# spring security 4.x authentication layer is not invoked

Tags: spring, spring-security

Am trying to upgrade from spring security 3.x to 4.x. Have done all the changes as the spring guide says. Still, not able to get the fruit. Let me add the code snippet which contains all the configuration of security i have implemented.

Parent_Pom

```
<spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <!-- will come with all needed Spring dependencies such as spring-core 
            and spring-beans -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring security stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>  
            <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>               
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>             
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>             
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Child Pom

```
<!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring security stuff -->

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
   <param-value>com.sbna.dealerportal.web.CustomContextInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
   <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Listener to support spring security-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
         </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>classpath:context-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/no-access</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

context-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.security"/>

<sec:http use-expressions="true">

    <!-- List secure pages and the users that can access them -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="${url.channel}"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="${url.channel}"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/app/inbox" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_VENDOR', 'ROLE_BUYER', 'ROLE_APPROVER', 'ROLE_AUDITOR')" requires-channel="${url.channel}"/>

    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/app" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_VENDOR', 'ROLE_BUYER', 'ROLE_APPROVER', 'ROLE_AUDITOR')" requires-channel="${url.channel}"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_VENDOR', 'ROLE_BUYER', 'ROLE_APPROVER', 'ROLE_AUDITOR')" requires-channel="${url.channel}"/>


    <!-- public pages here -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="${url.channel}"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>

    <sec:form-login
        login-page="/login"
        login-processing-url="/process-login"
        password-parameter="password"
        username-parameter="username"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>

    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>

</sec:http>

<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.project.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.project.security.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.project.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <!-- <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/> -->
</beans:bean>

<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Have shared all the code related to spring security. On trying to login into application, authentication is not called , error is thrown, finally leads to no-access page. Can anyone help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that your login page is also secured by the access rules. Try adding a rule that'll allow anyone to access the login page. Something like this:

```
<sec:http pattern="/login*" security="none"/>
<sec:http use-expressions="true">

    <!-- List secure pages and the users that can access them -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="${url.channel}"/>
```